# ATI HD5570 DDR3 2GB or HD5670 DDR5 1GB?

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, desktop-computer

I don't know whether to post this this on gaming or here, so I just pick one since it's not about game.. Hope u guys know this, which one is better in terms of best value for money?? or better yet, suggest a better one (nvidia maybe??)

- ATI HD5570 DDR3 2GB
- ATI HD5670 DDR5 1GB (more expensive)

Comment: Unfortunately shopping recommendations are off topic on Super User. I'm not sure they're on topic on Gaming either.

Comment: thx for reminding me that.. I'm new here..

Comment: Don't worry - even users who've been around for a while forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which of these cards to pick depends on how you are using it.

The DDR3 2GB will be able to handle more textures as it has more memory.

The DDR5 1GB will be able to access the textures faster, giving a smoother experience, but at the cost of less cached textures.

So, if you want better textures, go for the cheaper one.  If you want smoother rendering, go for the more expensive one.

Comment: thx for that!! I'll take note..